# How to merge two lists horizontally

Tags: python, list-comprehension

EDIT: I am using zip, but as my environment is in Python 2.x the zip code is matching character by character instead of items in list 1 with items in list 2

I am trying to merge two lists horizontally. My sample dataset is something like this:

```
test_list1 = ['1', '4', '5', '6', '5'] 
test_list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
```

I want the outcome of the combined list to look like this:

```
Combined_list = ['1a', '4b', '5c', '6d', '5e']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use zip:

```
[f"{x[0]}{x[1]}" for x in zip(test_list1, test_list2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip to iterate through two lists in parallel

```
test_list1 = ['1', '4', '5', '6', '5'] 
test_list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

Combined_list = [f_item + s_item for f_item, s_item in zip(test_list1, test_list2)]
```

Comment: Hey ginkul, I think another approach I might need to take is to get the same output for a list in a list i.e [ ['1', '4', '5', '6', '5'], ['a','b','c','d','e'] ] . In this case, how would I iterate over this to get ['1a', '4b', '5c', '6d', '5e'] ?

Comment: @clover it would be almost the same: `Combined_list = [f + s for f, s in zip(initial_list[0], initial_list[1])]`. List comprehension is a damn good thing to get a list from the other list

Answer (score 1):

By using `zip` and `join`:

```
test_list1 = ['1', '4', '5', '6', '5'] 
test_list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

[''.join(t) for t in zip(test_list1, test_list2)]
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, while this code is working fine on my Jupyter notebook with the latest Python version, it doesn't seem to be working in Python 2.7 environment as it's merging the first character from the first list, with the first character from the second list, I actually want it to match the first list item instead which is longer than just a '1'..it could consist of 4-5 words or longer.